# Python 20 teams 6bowlers each

Tags: python

Assignment Description: There are 6 members per team and 20 teams in the league.  Each bowler needs their score (between 0 and 300) to be entered.  The winning team is found by determining the highest average score.  Output the team’s name and average that wins the competition. NO arrays used.

For this problem, how would one nest if statements so it continues down if the team number is below 12, then continue to check if the member number is below 8?

```
def inputScore():
    totalScore = 0
    for team in range (1,13):
      team = int(input("Team number: "))
      while (team<0 or team>13):
         team = int(input("Invalid input. Enter team number 1-12: "))
      bowler = int(input("Enter bowler number: "))
      while (bowler<0 or bowler>8):
         bowler = int(input("Invalid input. Enter bowler number 1-8 "))
      score = int(input("Enter score: "))
      while (score<0 or score>300):
         score = int(input("Invalid input. Enter score 0-300: "))
      total=(bowler*score)
      totalScore=totalScore + total
    return totalScoretotalAvg=inputScore()
    avg=totalAvg/8
print ("The highest score for teams are: ", avg)
```

Here's what I have now, I know there's stuff wrong with it. I'm not quite sure how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: You need to format your code so that it is understandable @sirsand.  Highlight the code and press the {} button at the top of the edit box

Comment: Don't edit your problem out of your question once your problem is solved because the question and answers no longer make sense to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis `score = int(input("Enter bowler's score: "))`

EDIT: Partial answer:

```
def getTeamScore(teamNumber):
    print("Scores for team " + str(teamNumber))
    score1 = int(input("Score for player 1: "))
    score2 = int(input("Score for player 2: "))
    return (score1 + score2) / 2 #Remember parenthesis here


bestScore = -1
bestTeam = 0

for teamNumber in range(1, 3):
    teamScore = getTeamScore(teamNumber)
    if (teamScore > bestScore):
        bestScore = teamScore
        bestTeam = teamNumber

print("Best team: " + str(bestTeam) + " with score: " + str(bestScore))
```

Comment: Also, need to add one more space in the indent for that line.

Comment: Sounds to me you should familiarize yourself with multidimensional arrays and for loops. Check for example the [this tutorial](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch20s05.html). You would have an array of teams, where each index would hold an array of that team's scores. Using only if statements would result in quite a long and repetitive code, if you actually need to calculate each team's scores.

Comment: Why can't you use arrays? Is it an assignment on a course or something and arrays aren't covered? I don't think there is much help from for loops if you do not use arrays. Also, where do you get the scores for the teams? Do you define them yourself? If you have an assignment description, please do add it to your question.

Comment: If you can't use arrays, then you can make a function that returns the average score of a team. The function would have 8 input statements, and all of them would be stored in variables score1, score2, ... Then you would return the sum of score1 ... score8 divided by 8 for the average. Then in the main part of the program you would call this function 12 times, once for each team. You could keep track of the current winning team by storing in variables the # and average score of the winning team, updating them when a better team is found. It takes quite a lot more work without arrays, though...

Comment: I added a partial answer for comparing two teams. Please do take the time to try and understand it well.

Comment: I edited my answer again now to use for loops (dunno why I didn't use it at first). The main problem with your approach was, that it would need arrays. Each time you write `score = VALUE` you are overwriting the previous value. Thus, you can't use only 1 variable (score) to calculate the average of 8 scores. You need variables score1, score2 etc to hold scores of each player, because you need all of those scores simultaneously, which isn't possible if you keep overwriting the value. So basically edit the `range` function parameters and add score inputs for the rest in my answer to complete.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps you to further your understanding! Don't forget to choose the answer as the accepted answer. Also, in the future check the instructions for formatting the code you copy paste to your text, so we can understand it better :)

Comment: In my example you don't need to since, using `range(1, 13)` means you go through teams 1 to 12 in order. And in the function you explicitly ask for the scores of player 1, player 2 until player 8. The bowler number is explicitly written into the code logic, it is not asked from the user. Same goes for the team number too. The score on the other, you need to ask after each input. For example after `score1 = int(input("Score for player 1: "))` you can use the while loop to ask for a score until it is in the range of 0 to 300. You add this check to each score variable (score1, score2...)